# PHP error: array object converted into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array

I am making a CRUD application using Codeigniter 3.

Whenever I edit a record and the data is *invalid*, instead of just showing the validation error messages, the browser outputs the message: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

My update function inside the **controller** looks like this:

```
public function update($customer_id) {
    // data validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data = [
        // insert into these database table fields
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
        'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address')
        ];
        $this->load->model('Customer');
        if ($this->Customer->updateCustomer($customer_id, $data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('update-response','Customer successfully updated');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('update-response','Failed to update customer');
        }
        redirect('home');
    } else {
    $data = [       
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'id' => $customer_id
    ];
    $this->load->view('update', ['customer' => $data]);
 }
}
```

If the data in the update form is valid there are no errors. the form looks like this:

```
<?php echo form_open("home/update/{$customer->id}"); ?>

            <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
                <?php echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', $customer->first_name),[
                    'id' => 'first_name',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                if(form_error('first_name')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
                echo form_error('first_name'); ?>                                     
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('last_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
                <?php echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name', $customer->last_name), [
                    'id' => 'last_name',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                if(form_error('last_name')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
                echo form_error('last_name'); ?> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
                <?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $customer->email), [
                    'id' => 'email',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                if(form_error('email')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
                echo form_error('email'); ?> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('phone')) echo 'has-error';?>">
                <?php echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone', $customer->phone), [
                    'id' => 'phone',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                if(form_error('phone')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
                echo form_error('phone'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('country')) echo 'has-error';?>">
                <?php echo form_input('country', set_value('country', $customer->country), [
                    'id' => 'country',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                if(form_error('country')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
                echo form_error('country'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_input('city', set_value('city', $customer->city), [
                    'id' => 'city',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_input('address', set_value('city', $customer->address), [
                    'id' => 'address',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class = "btn btn-success btn-block"'); ?>
            </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I believe `$customer` is turned into an associative array and this is the reason for the error message: `Trying to get property of non-object`. But what is causing this conversion? Or is the cause of the problem completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what is causing this conversion?

Nothing, you pass an array and you get an array which you try to access like an object.

In your example, `$data` is an array, but in your view you are accessing it like an object.

If you really want to access it like an object, cast the array to object:

```
$this->load->view('update', ['customer' => (object)$data]);
```

Comment: What exactly to optimize? I don't see much to do there given the fact it's just a simple form, just watch out when you echo variables in the views, make sure you encode them to avoid any XSS issues.

Comment: Isn't CI safe out of the box?

Comment: Please search and see what XSS is and how it can be prevented ;)